# Is there anything like C++ static_assert for Haxe?

Tags: haxe, static-assert

I want to do compile-time assertions in Haxe. It would be nice to do something like:

```
static inline var important_number = 42;

public function f():Void {
    static_assert(important_number > 64, "important number is too small for this implementation!");
}
```

My question is: are Haxe macros the right route here, otherwise what is the best way to do compile-time assertions in Haxe?

Below I have a macro which works for this if you just pass it true/false (though I suppose it should be returning nothing or a noop). But I am unsure how to make this work for the more general case of "anything that eventually becomes a boolean at compile-time".

```
class Assert {
/* Static assert */
macro static public function s(e:Expr, errorString:String):Expr {
    switch(e.expr) {
        case EConst(c):
            switch(c) {
                case CIdent("true"):
                    return e;
                case CIdent("false"):
                    throw new Error(errorString, e.pos);
                default:
                    throw new Error("I only accept true/false right now", e.pos);
            }
        default:
            throw new Error("I only accept true/false right now", e.pos);
    }
}
}

Assert.s(false, "yep, it's a compile time error");
Assert.s(true, "business as usual");
Assert.s(6 == 9, "i don't seem to work yet");
```

Update 1:

There is #error which can be used for some simple cases like:

```
#if ios
    trace("it just works!");
#else
    #error("you didn't implement this yet!");
#end
```

Solution:

So here is what I'm using now, there are probably caveats but it seems to work for simple static assertions:

```
import haxe.macro.Context;
import haxe.macro.Expr;
import haxe.macro.ExprTools;

class Assert {
    /* Static assert */
    macro static public function s(expr:Expr, ?error:String):Expr {
        if (error == null) {
            error = "";
        }

        if (expr == null) {
            throw new Error("Expression must be non-null", expr.pos);
        }

        var value = ExprTools.getValue(Context.getTypedExpr(Context.typeExpr(expr)));

        if (value == null) {
            throw new Error("Expression value is null", expr.pos);
        }
        else if (value != true && value != false) {
            throw new Error("Expression does not evaluate to a boolean value", expr.pos);
        }
        else if(value == false) {
            throw new Error("Assertion failure: " + ExprTools.toString(expr) + " " + "[ " + error + " ]", expr.pos);
        }

        return macro { };
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your macro have to do with static assertions? It throws an Error, which would be runtime rather than compile-time, right?

Comment: No, it is compile-time error.

Comment: @Gama11 Assuming macro are only evaluated at compile time, then surely the throwing has to happen then too.

Comment: Well, there are [different kinds of macros](http://haxe.org/manual/macro.html). The one in your example is an expression macro, but you can call `Context.fatalError()` from both build and initialization macros to throw a compiler error.

Comment: That `throw` in the macro function is indeed **compile-time error**. To cause a run-time throw, it would be `return macro throw ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To evaluate an `Expr` and get the value of it at compile-time, we can use [ExprTools.getValue](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/ExprTools.html#getValue). Looking at its [source](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/3.1.3/std/haxe/macro/ExprTools.hx#L212), it is in fact using a technique similar to the one posted in the question.

Making it even more robust, we can do `ExprTools.getValue(Context.getTypedExpr(Context.typeExpr(expr)))` , such that all inline variables or even macro functions inside `expr` will be resolved.

For returning a no-op, we can simply `return macro {};`.